# How to get Kafka bootstrap configuration setting from Kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

Question for Kafka experts:

Anyone knows how to get worker's config setting 'bootstrap.servers' either from SinkConnector or SinkTask? Or how to get Kafka cluster information from connector?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the Connect API doesn't provide this information right now.
If you need this functionality, perhaps your best bet is to open a JIRA on the Apache Kafka project and explain the use-case (i.e. what are you planning on doing this information).

Comment: Thanks, Gwen, for your reply. The use case is pretty simple to redirect some messages to the error topic. At the moment my workaround is to set up additional setting for producer which forwards some messages to the error topic (for example when SQL error happens).

Comment: Ah, got it! We are working on building error handling right into the framework, so you wouldn't need to do it in the connector.

Comment: Awesome! It would be great to have this functionality.